# How to set maintenance mode with django in stateless aplication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-run, stateless

I've hosted my app in Google Cloud Run, a simple Vue's frontend connected to a django API. The problem arises when I try  to set maintenance mode to the API, protecting it from unexpected calls. For this purpose I've used [django-maintenance-mode](https://pypi.org/project/django-maintenance-mode/)'s package, but, as I said, due to the implicit stateless character of GC Run, the enviroment variable that stores the maintenance mode's value drops when there isn't any active instance, getting back to OFF.

I'd like to know any other possible solution or fix overriding any of this package's methods to make it work in my project.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Graceful shutdowns](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/graceful-shutdowns-cloud-run-deep-dive) which will allow you to capture the environment variable that stores the maintenance mode value. Once the value is captured you can store it in a database (Cloud SQL) or in a file on Cloud Storage. At each startup, you get the last value.